# Format color for HTML/jquery table cells based on the cell value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML that uses jquery to pull in data from a csv file and display it in a table. I am trying to do some conditional formatting on the resulting table. I want any cell with a value below 2.5 to be set to a green background. Values between 2.5 and 3 should be yellow. Any value between 3 and 100 should be red. I have tried numerous different solutions that are provided here on the website, but none have worked so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatiable" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Inspection</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120">


</head>
<body>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function opsi(data){
    var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table = "<table id='scrapT'>";
    for(var singleRow=0;singleRow<allRows.length;singleRow++){
        if(singleRow === 0){
            table += "<thead>";
            table += "<tr>";
        } else{
            table += "<tr>";
        }
        var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
        for(var rowSingleCell=0;rowSingleCell<rowCells.length;rowSingleCell++){
            if(singleRow === 0){
                table += "<th>";
                table += rowCells[rowSingleCell];
                table += "</th>";
            } else{
                table += "<td>";
                table += rowCells[rowSingleCell];
                table += "</td>";
            }
        }
        if(singleRow === 0){
            table += "</tr>";
            table += "</thead>";
            table += "<tbody>";
        } else{
            table += "</tr>";
        }
    }
    table += "</tbody";
    table += "</table>";
    $("body").append(table);
}

$.ajax({
    url: "file.csv",
    dataType: "text"
}).done(opsi);

</script>
```